# Base URL is not coming correctly in AJAX call on landing page of sub site

Tags: routing, ajax, sitecore-mvc

My current Sitecore project has a multisite with URL structure as follows

- [www.MainSite.com](http://www.MainSite.com)
- [www.MainSite.com/SubSite](http://www.MainSite.com/SubSite)

Whenever I do an AJAX call from the `subsite` landing page the base URL is coming as `www.MainSite.com` and on inner pages (`www.MainSite.com/SubSite/innerpage`) of the sub site, the base URL is coming as `www.MainSite.com/SubSite` in AJAX calls.

I need the base URL to come as  `www.MainSite.com/SubSite` on the landing page as well, so that the AJAX calls will work using one route entry.

When I put an extra slash at the end of the landing page URL (`www.MainSite.com/SubSite/`), the AJAX call is working.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: As you said when you use an extra slash in your URL then the Ajax call is working. So did you try adding that extra slash in your ajax call like `$.ajax({
url: '/api/sitecore/<ControllerName>/<ActionName>',`

Comment: if I add like '/api/sitecore/<ControllerName>/ on ajax base url will come www.MainSite.com. but I need subSite as well on the url

Comment: I think your system is not resolving the site. Did you check this setting? `<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolving" value="true"/>`

Comment: this setting is already there. system is resolving the site only when the url have / after the starting item (home page)